# ETF market during severe crash

Tags: financial-economics, soft-question, market-failure

**Question**: Does the decentralized creation and redemption process make ETFs fragile in case of a market crash?

While the idea of ETFs is obviously great, I am a bit skeptical whether the tradeability makes them fragile. The creation and redemption process basically depends on market makers wanting to exchange stocks for issues of the ETF fund. But these authorized parties' incentive to engage in this work is to make small arbitrage gains. That is a no-brainer business in good times, but will it also work during a crash?

Imagine there is a serious crash in the indexes (like 60% or more), and many retailers start liquidating putting further liquidation pressure on funds. Perhaps we enter a situation where people loose trust in ETFs. Surely at some point the market makers will not want to buy stake in the ETFs anymore? Also, note that issuers can close funds anytime and they have an incentive to that when contributions drop. In that case retailers may be forced to sell at the lowest prices because issuers.

**Addendum:** Found an [ECB research paper](https://www.esrb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/asc/esrb.asc190617_9_canetfscontributesystemicrisk%7E983ea11870.en.pdf) that mentions these risks

*Such decoupling of ETF and constituent securities prices can originate from APs and OLPs
not having the incentives and capacity to realign them in times of financial stress.* (p. 26) and also

*If investors anticipate a breakdown in the liquidity transformation operated by ETFs, this
could lead to market fragility: large deviations of ETF prices from the value of the underlying
securities may induce investors to lose faith in the market valuation of those securities as
well*

Comment: then the arbitrage gain would be large instead of small, no? Buy ETFs for 40% of the price, redeem them for some fee, and sell the stocks for 99% of the price.  The main reason a market maker *wouldn't* do this is that they think the ETF company won't let them redeem the ETF.